# CListCtrl is showing different theme for Unicode and Multi byte character set

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

List Control theme is showing different theme while changing the character set:
[image: Unicode vs Multi Byte]

Code Snippet,

```
private:
CListCtrl m_list;

m_list.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
// TODO: Add extra initialization here

// Ask Mfc to create/insert a column
m_list.InsertColumn(
    0,              // Rank/order of item
    L"Name",         // Caption for this header
    LVCFMT_LEFT,    // Relative position of items under header
    100);          // Width of items under header

m_list.InsertColumn(1, L"Profession", LVCFMT_CENTER, 80);
m_list.InsertColumn(2, L"Fav. Sport", LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);
m_list.InsertColumn(3, L"Hobby", LVCFMT_LEFT, 80);

int nItem;

nItem = m_list.InsertItem(0, L"Sandra C. Anschwitz");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, L"Singer");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 2, L"HandBall");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 3, L"Beach");

nItem = m_list.InsertItem(0, L"Roger A. Miller");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, L"FootBaller");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 2, L"Tennis");
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 3, L"Teaching");
```

How to get the Unicode theme in Multi Byte character set?

Comment: please add sample code for more understand

Comment: it is just a normal ListView Control code, but showing different themes for the different character sets.

Comment: AFAICS this is not related to CListCtrl at all. The "OK" button is not themed either. The question should be: "Why is my program themed when I compile witn MBCS but not themed when I compile it with UNICODE".

Comment: Both are different theme, right?

Comment: @iamsreesn you may want to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/visual-styles-overview

Comment: You may have selected different build configurations for Release/Debug, and they use different character set as well different manifest for visual style.

Comment: Yes, when you generate an VC++ MFC app wizard application, it adds a conditional manifest dependency for Common Controls 6.0 that is only enabled for UNICODE applications. There are technical notes (or at least Raymond Chen) to say why not to include Common Controls 6.0 in your MBCS application. That is likely why it is themed differently.

Answer (score 3):

If you generated this project using an app wizard in Visual C++, you probably have these lines in your stdafx.h file:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

This is the reason you are themed differently.  There are [technical reasons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081106-00/?p=20303) to not use Common Controls 6 in your MBCS application. However, if you can build for UNICODE successfully, just do that. Any supported Windows OS is UNICODE capable and that is what you should be using anyways. Just say NO to MBCS.