# CMFCButton with Icon or Bitmap shows only a cut off text?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Why show `CMFCButton` only a cut off text ?

Can be shown and reproduce in VS2019, Button added in `IDD_ABOUTBOX`.

[image]

Comment: The image does not prove that the text is truncated. Perhaps it was short in the first place? Show your code.

Comment: All the code is in the ressorce editor. I just added here a standard MFCButton. The standart Text is MFCButton. Please someone try and confirm it?

Comment: I tried. You must have done something different: I do not get an image without writing code even when I choose Image type Bitmap. Show your code.

Comment: I've had vaguely similar issues caused by conflicts between the "Unicode/Multibyte" setting for the project and the format of the string literal being used as the button label/text. Check that they are compatible (i.e. literal with or without the `L".."` prefix).

Comment: Your resource script *is* code. Please show that code (not the entire resource script, just a [mcve]).

Comment: @AdrianMole Bingo, I see this only if MBCS is set. In UNICODE is fine.  But I could still not yet fix it for MBCS. Additional Info: my Button has the style Moving Type horizontal too,

Answer (score 0):

I could now isolate and reproduce and fix the problem. (thanks to a remember from a.mole)

If you generated this project using an app wizard in Visual C++, you probably have these lines in your stdafx.h  (or framework.h in the newer version) file:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
  #if defined _M_IX86
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #elif defined _M_X64
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #else
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #endif
#endif
```

[image]

All fine!

Now, in my older project I had comment out ifdef _UNICODE to use the same manifest in MBCS too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631066/4303373

```
//#ifdef _UNICODE
  #if defined _M_IX86
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #elif defined _M_X64
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #else
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
  #endif
//#endif
```

[image]

Conclusion: You should not change MS generated code, this may not work correct in a future version.